# List comprehension not working as intended

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say my dataframe is like this:

[image]

Used the following code to split data inside each column:

```
    col_names = ['col1','col2','col3']
    for i in range(len(df)):
        s = tuple(zip(df[col_names[0]].str.split(",")[i],df[col_names[1]].str.split(",")[i],df[col_names[2]].str.split(",")[i])
```

I changed this code so that it works dynamically to work for a variable number of columns in col_names using list comprehension as seen below:

```
for i in range (len(df)):
    s = tuple(zip(df[col].str.split(",")[i] for col in col_names)
```

Initial code used to give output as:

[image]

But now after adding list comprehension it looks like:

[image]

what is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 3):

1. Your code is extremely inefficient since it's calling `df[col].str.split(",")` over and over again for every `i`.
2. Your immediate bug is the `zip`.  You are passing it a single iterator as an argument.  You need to pass it multiple arguments.  The correct way to convert is `zip(*(........))`

Comment: Now entire dataframe rows(for i =0,1,2...etc) are getting into 's' variable.